# Melodic Fragments and Idioms

Tags: theory, piano, harmony, chord-progressions

Could someone please explain what melodic fragments are? I’ve been told that if you see scale degrees 123 or 321 in the melody or bass it calls for an idiom. I’ve also heard that there are other melodic fragments.

Comment: I might be assuming here, but: the term "idiom" suggests to me that you're learning from a particular type of music-theory curriculum. I teach in this manner, so I'd be happy to help, but explaining these idioms would take much more than a single answer here. I wonder if it would be best to go straight to your teacher?

Comment: I agree with you that I should go straight to my teacher. Thanks. I was wondering if you could maybe list some other fragments if you know? For example scale degrees 221?

Comment: If you‘d  look up the gregorian chant link I‘ve posted in my answer you could see that the most used neumes like  232, 323, 132 etc. have latin terms like sandicus, torculus etc. and they are called idioms.

Answer (score 4):

In this pedagogical approach, these harmonic idioms are taught as common building blocks that will aid both a) your aural comprehension of common-practice music, as well as b) your ability to harmonize and even improvise in this style (assuming you practice them at the keyboard).

There are a lot of common idioms used, so I'll just introduce a few here. Note that all are named after their soprano scale degrees, which helps one quickly insert them into chorale harmonizations:

1–2–3 or 3–2–1, so named because this one is actually reversible (meaning it can go in either direction):

[image]

8–7–6–5, which can also end on a V chord instead of tonic:

[image]

5–6–7–8, lesser used but still a clever tonic expansion:

[image]

And, because you specifically mentioned it, 2–2–1. Note that you double the 2 in the opening to prevent an augmented second from the A♭ to B♮:

[image]

Comment: All the examples are in C minor? Are the idioms for major the same but without accidentals needed for IV and V and I is major? I think I’m being taught something similar right now but without the same terms used and it just being called “scale harmonization".

Comment: Yes, for some reason I decided to put them all in C minor. But the same rules hold true in major, although the voice leading in the last example may be different in the ii6 since there's no augmented second. Otherwise the chords function exactly the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Idioms or fragments in the language of music are called motives, ornaments or groups of notes, as the head motive, the mordent or the final group in the section of a sonata. Usually they are called phrases or a clauses.

The idioms your teacher mentioned will be developed by the **neume** and later as well by the technique of playing the organ, piano or any keyboard as there are notes of passages  between thirds, fourths and fifths and change notes  by the intervals of  seconds.

look up the neume:

[image]

and especially the 3 notes neumes:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neume

Such idioms are  developed from the ornaments (melisma and ligatures) of the Gregorian chant (plain chant). You will find there a dozen of similar idioms.

"*In Western music, the term "melisma" most commonly refers to Gregorian chant (the first definition of melisma by the Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary'[2] is "a group of notes or tones sung on one syllable in plainsong"). However, the term melisma may be used to describe music of any genre, including baroque singing and later gospel."*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melisma

But idioms are also built and developed by the technics of certain instruments:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_idiom

Comment: Also known as *motif* (Fr.), *motiv* (Ger.) and *motivo* (It.). Beethoven's fifth is literally full of them.

Comment: when using Kopfmotiv I was right thinking of Beethoven's fifth. But almost all classical concerts and sonatas, also in baroque and romantic time had their own "idioms", to which we can not only count the motives and phrases but also typical chord progressions as the fifth fall cadence cannot just the head motives, as well in the 20th century composers have created their idioms and finally developed  their own language.

Answer (score 1):

The examples of harmonic idioms above are indicative of the sorts of melodic fragments you've asked about. I'd only remind you that each melodic fragment can be harmonized in additional ways. And I agree that learning these (and other) "melodic building blocks" will help anyone compose and improvise melody.

And it's here that we have a clue about a curious pedagogical practice that went out of vogue sometime in the 19th century.

It used to be that anyone who wanted to learn composition had to spend a few years doing something no student today would tolerate for a even few days: copy music by hand. Copying seems like a pointless assignment until you realize what an intelligent mind inevitably does with a mundane task:
finds shortcuts.

At first, the inexperienced copyist would work one note at a time: look at G, copy G, look at A, copy A, look at B, copy B, and so on. But it wouldn’t take long before he started assimilating groups of notes: look at G-A-B, copy G-A-B, look at C-B-C, copy C-B-C. And after a while, he could just glance at a group of notes – memorizing its shape and copying it perfectly without even thinking about note names.

Guess what happened when it was time to start composing; Did the student plod along one note at a time? Not likely! The figures he copied over and over would come to mind as gestures that he could combine to make his own melodies.

With that in mind, here's a graphic I made that collects the melodic patterns one would likely learn after copying dozens of scores. Keep in mind that they are in something like "root position" in that they begin on the root of C major harmony. Each pattern can begin on the other chord tones. And all of the patterns can be inverted. All but five are retrogradable. If any of the names may feel unfamiliar, it's because they offer mnemonic cues for learning the patterns.

[image: The 24 Universal Melodic Figures]
For further information and examples of each melodic figure in use, here's a link to an interactive version of my graphic: https://figuringoutmelody.com/the-24-universal-melodic-figures/

Comment: I object to the website's claim that "Every melody you know—plus every melody you don’t yet know—comes from just 24 melodic patterns or “figures.”" None of the website's 24 melodic patterns contains an octave leap, for example ("Somewhere Over the Rainbow"'s distinctive melody starts with an ascending octave leap).

Comment: On further reflection, this does provide a reasonable answer to this web page's question, but this fails to disclose that the website https://figuringoutmelody.com/the-24-universal-melodic-figures/ mentioned in this answer is a website its answerer directs. The answerer's bio, however, discloses that.

Comment: I have reluctantly flagged this answer as spam as a result - the web page https://music.stackexchange.com/help/promotion, which a link to appears when flagging something as spam, says that "However, if you mention your product, website, etc. in your question or answer, you must disclose your affiliation in your post."

Comment: As for Over the Rainbow, octave leaps are chordal leaps, which means they fall under the arpeggiation category. The figures on this table are 3- and 4-note figures. They appear in every melody I have been able to find for over three decades. That said, I also have a list of melodic dyads, as well as explaining how to form 5- 6- and 7-note patterns aby conjoining the 24 figures. 
As for your concern about disclosure, I'm still trying to learn the ropes here. Sorry if I transgressed.  As per your comments, I edited my answer.  Hope it is better now? Thanks!

Comment: It does look better - this time, you do indicate that you made the graphic of melodic figures.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way for you to remove your reluctant flag? 

Also, if you have more questions about this project, I FIND THEM ALL HELPFUL! (You'll see that I tweaked my blog post based on your earlier comment.) Feel free to reach out.

Comment: Yes - I retracted my flag just now.